# insert data into mysql from a file using join

Tags: php, mysql

I have data (account number) that is missing from one of my tables and im trying to add that data from a file. The table that is missing the data is called 'custom_65275887', the problem i am having is to be able to insert the data to the correct column i have to join the 'custom_65275887' table to another table called 'vicidial_list' be cause this table has a phone number that i am going to use to compare existing data and incoming data. these two table have the 'lead_id' column in common but the incoming data file doesn't have this 'lead_id' data.

```
    insert into custom_65275587(account) 

                value
                   ($fileop[1])
                join
                   vicidial_list
                on

                custom_65275587.lead_id = vicidial_list.lead_id

                where
                   vicidial_list.phone_number = $fileop[0]
```

$fileop[1] is the account number
$fileop[0] is the phone number

when running this command in php using the variables or in phpMyAdmin with populated data i get a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax should be something like the following.

```
insert into custom (X, X) values (X, X) from custom a
join vicidial_list b on a.key = b.key
where b.key = $variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked.

```
     update custom_65275587

                join
                   vicidial_list
                on
                   vicidial_list.lead_id = custom_65275587.lead_id
                set
                   custom_65275587.account = $fileop[1]
                where
                   vicidial_list.phone_number = $fileop[0]
```